# Split special string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to split the below string with given output. 
Can anybody help me to do this.

**Examples**:

1. /TEST/TEST123

Output: /Test/

2. /TEST1/Test/Test/Test/

Output: /Test1/

3. /Text/12121/1212/

Output: /Text/

4. /121212121/asdfasdf/

Output: /121212121/

5. 12345

Output: 12345

I have tried string.split function but it is not worked well. Is there any idea or logic that i can implement to achieve this situation.
If the answer in regular expression that would be fine for me.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Out of those 4 examples it's a bit hard to guess the logic how you want the strings to be split. The `String.Split()` method most likely does the trick, if you just say how do you want it done. Also show what you have tried.

Comment: I know its a hard that's why i post his question here. I have tried simple split function which split string with '/'. It only split and return the character at array's [1] position.

Comment: @V.J. Just want to confirm.. For result of number 2, the first letter is upper case and the rest of them are lower case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
    string s1 = "/TEST/TEST123";
    string s2 = "/TEST1/Test/Test/Test/";
    string s3 = "/Text/12121/1212/";
    string s4 = "/121212121/asdfasdf/";
    string s5 = "12345";

    string pattern = @"\/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?";

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s1, pattern)[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s2, pattern)[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s3, pattern)[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s4, pattern)[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s5, pattern)[0]);
```

Comment: Your regular expression is works for me. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 6):

You simply want the first result of Spiting by `/`

```
string output = input.Split('/')[0];
```

But in case that you have `//TEST/` and output should be `/TEST` you can use regex.

```
string output = Regex.Matches(input, @"\/?(.+?)\/")[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

For your 5th case : you have to separate the logic. for example:

```
public static string Method(string input)
{
    var split = input.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (split.Length == 0) return input;
    return split[0];
}
```

Or using regex.

```
public static string Method(string input)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\/?(.+?)\/");
    if (matches.Count == 0) return input;
    return matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Some results using method:

```
TEST/54/    =>   TEST
TEST        =>   TEST
/TEST/      =>   TEST
```

Comment: he needs to separate the logic. wait i fix it.

Comment: This regex will capture all cases and there is no need to separate logic: `\/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?`

Answer (score 2):

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string example = "/TEST/TEST123";

            var result = GetFirstItem(example);

            Console.WriteLine("First in the list : {0}", result);

        }

        static string GetFirstItem(string value)
        {
            var collection = value?.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var result = collection[0];
            return result;
        }
    }
```

[`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enum which tells the `Split` function that when it has split the string into an array, if there are elements in the array that are empty strings, the function should not include the empty elements in the results. Basically you want the collection to contain only values.

Comment: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is an enum which tells the Split function that when it has split the string into an array and if there is any elements in the array that is an empty string, the function should not include the empty elements in the results. Basically you want the collection to contain only values

Comment: Nice answer. This is what I'd go for.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string functionName(string input)
{
    if(input.Contains('/'))
    {
        string SplitStr = input.Split('/')[1];
        return "/"+SplitStr .Substring(0, 1) +SplitStr.Substring(1).ToLower()+"/"
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and time. Let me check ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = @"/Text/12121/1212/";
    int first = test.IndexOf("/");
    int last = test.Substring(first+1).IndexOf("/");
    string finall = test.Substring(first, last+2);
}
```

i try this code with all your examples and get correct output. try this.

Answer (score 1):

The following method may help you.

```
 public string getValue(string st)
 {
     if (st.IndexOf('/') == -1)
         return st;
     return "/" + st.Split('/')[1] + "/";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = (output.Contains("/"))? '/' +input.Split('/')[1]+'/':input;
```